# How to combine 2 matrices into a graph

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have 2 symmetric matrices (mathematical meaning of matrices), one with distances between locations (the locations are coded with 4 digit numbers:2030, 2059, 2095...) that looks like this:
`2030    2059    2095 ...

2030    NA  59328   68464

2059    59328   NA  37196

2095    68464   37196   NA

...`

and another with the correlations between locations :
`2030      2059    2095...

2030   1.0000000 0.4651804 0.6185849

2059   0.4651804 1.0000000 0.4428746

2095   0.6185849 0.4428746 1.0000000

...`

I need to combine these 2 matrices in a plot of correlations vs. distances but have no idea how to do it in R and considering I have more than 80 locations I don't want to do it manually! Does anyone know of a way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to plot correlations as a function of distances, without imposing a particular structure on your plot, you can just extract the lower part of your respective matrices, e.g.

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=20)
d.mat <- as.matrix(dist(x))
c.mat <- cor(t(x))
plot(d.mat[lower.tri(d.mat)], c.mat[lower.tri(c.mat)])
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your matrices are stored in `m1` and `m2`, does this work:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=as.vector(m1[upper.tri(m1)]),
          b=as.vector(m2[upper.tri(m2)]))
plot(dat$a,dat$b)
```

Comment: +1 it seems we answered quite at the same time, suggesting almost the same solution.

Comment: Thanks guys! Unfortunately I can only accept 1 answer but +1 for Joran